# sync and async status of Operation and OperationQueues

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I am reading docs on OperationQueue.

I have this doubt, what is the sync and async status of the operation, BlockOperation and OperationQueue we are creating.

As I am understanding it, it will run as sync operation, but in case we want to run it in async manner we have to dispatch it it in async manner using dispatch.async.

Am I understanding it right?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139280/discussion-on-question-by-jean-luc-godard-sync-and-async-status-of-operation-and).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronous operation will be seen as completed by `OperationQueue` when the block you submit to `BlockOperation` returns (or `main` method if you subclass `Operation`)

Asynchronous operation (that is returning `true` from its `isAsynchronous` property), must be marked as finished manually in a subclass of `Operation` by setting `isFinished = true` (you should also set `isExecuting = false` at the same time). This allows you to dispatch whatever work you need to do to a different queue by using `Dispatch.async`, but still keep the operation in `OperationQueue`. This is useful to build dependant operations or to allow only certain amount of operations to run in parallel.

Apple's [Operation docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/operation) have good explanations for all of this.